# Fedora CoreOS Container Permissions to Create Directory

Tags: containers, fedora, fedora-coreos

I'm trying to run Plex Media Server on a fcos host. I keep getting a permissions error during launch.

```
find: ‘/config’: Permission denied
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/config/Library’: Permission denied
```

I've created directories like this on the host:

```
/var/plex/config
/var/plex/transcode
```

I've chown'd these with the core user and have set permissions on the plex, config, and transcode folders to 777 (as part of troubleshooting). I've specified in my docker-compose for the PMS server to set the UID and GID to match the user I'm using to launch the container. I've even tried to sudo docker-compose and it doesn't help.
Am I missing something with FCOS? I thought /var was supposed to be writable?

EDIT:
I updated my volume configuration to use the `:Z` option. Like so:

```
volumes:
  - /var/plex/config:/config:Z
  - /var/plex/transcode:/transcode:Z
  - /var/plex/plex-docker/fstab:/etc/fstab:Z
```

This fixed the problem, but I guess my question is why? Is this just an SELinux thing?